# trouble with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arraySum (int *a, int n);
int main(void){
    int values[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("The sum is %i\n", arraySum(values, 3));
    return 0;
}
int arraySum(int *a, int n){
    int sum = 0;
    int arrayEnd = *a + n;
    for ( ; *a < arrayEnd; *a++)
        sum += *a;
    return sum;
}
```

For some reason it outputs this:

```
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ gcc practice.c 
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ ./a.out
The sum is -421028781
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ ./a.out
The sum is -362865581
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ ./a.out
The sum is -1046881197
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ ./a.out
The sum is 6
roman@lmde64 ~/Dropbox/Practice $ ./a.out
The sum is 6
```

Why is the output strange numbers sometimes and the right answer other times?
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just checking... you know you can use array notation with pointers, right? This is a very convoluted way to access the elements of an array, rather than: `for(int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < n; arrayIndex++) { sum += a[arrayIndex]; }`

Comment: nope, I didn't. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `arraySum()`, you are confusing when to use `a` as a pointer, and when to dereference it to obtain what it is pointing to.  When you are calculating the loop limits, etc., you want to be working with the pointer *itself*:

```
int arraySum(int *a, int n){
    int sum = 0;
    int *arrayEnd = a + n;
    for ( ; a < arrayEnd; a++)
        sum += *a;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't explain the nondeterministic behavior, though. As far as I can tell, the program is perfectly well-formed and should in fact print 6.

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate over the array:

```
int arraySum(int *a, int n){
    int sum = 0;
    int * arrayEnd = a + n; // arrayEnd points to the first element after your array a
    for ( ; a != arrayEnd; ++a)  // Iterate over the array until you reach arrayEnd
        sum += *a; // Dereference the pointer to current array element in order to retrieve a value
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `*a++` is the same as `*(a++)`; the `*` does nothing in this instance
- arrayEnd gets set to `*a + 3`, or `1 + 3`, or `4`
- your for loop does not terminate before the array is exhausted. Accessing outside the array limits invokes **undefined behaviour**
- your program could just as well have output "The mighty sum is not what you expect!\n"

Comment: My understanding is that *a++ gets the int value that a is pointed to and then increments a.

Comment: Yes, @Richard; the value of `*a++` is what you say. Point is it doesn't do anything in the for loop: the simpler `a++` is enough

Comment: ok, so why does it terminate properly when I put `int * arrayEnd = a + n;` instead of just `arrayEnd` without the asteric

Comment: @lqdc: because then you are dealing with pointers, not integers. `a` is a pointer; `*a` is an integer; `a + n` is a pointer (points to the int `n` away from `a`); `*a + n` is an integer

Answer (score 1):

```
int arraySum(int *a, int n) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      sum += a[i];
   return sum;
}
```

or

```
int arraySum(int *a, int n) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
      sum += *a++;
   return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the original code,

- `*a + n` evaluates to `1+3 = 4`
- In every iteration of the `for` loop , the value pointed to by `*a` is compared with `4`.
- If the value `*a` is less than `4`, then the `sum` is computed.
- After 3 iterations, `a` is pointing to `values[2]` which is `3`. Later, when `a` is incremented, 
  it points to the address beyond `value[2]` -- this address can contain any garbage value.
  If the garbage value is less than `4`, it will compute `sum`. This behavior continues until
  a value greater than `4` is encountered. 
  **Hence the value of `sum` is sometimes `6` or some other garbage value**